# ''due to'' or ''because of''

Tags: grammar, phrases, nouns, adjectives

So I stumbled upon this sentence:

''Aside from a flexible vagina which is due to the pelvic muscles' elasticity [...]''

And I wonder, shouldn't there be ''because of''? Because it modifies the adjective ''flexible'', and for ''due to'' to be right shouldn't it have been ''the flexibility of vagina [...]'' ? But again, I know that ''due to'' must follow a form of ''to be'', which is present here.

Comment: There are some prescriptivists who would argue that the above use of "due to" is incorrect, and it should be "because of", but most native (US) English speakers will find the "due to" version perfectly proper and more natural-sounding.

Comment: You know that "due to" must follow a form of "to be" – [*or does it?*](http://articles.baltimoresun.com/2013-01-09/news/bal-the-foggy-foggy-due-20130109_1_copy-editor-defeat-objection)

Comment: As I explain in my answer, this question, despite its title, really hinges on a rather different issue than *due to* vs. *because of.* That is why I nominated it for re-opening.

Answer (score 1):

Over the years there has been some purist anxiety about whether *due to* or *owing to* can properly predicate a cause of a clause (the way *because* can) as well as of a noun or its syntactic equivalent; but that is not really the issue here. The intent is clearly to identify a cause for the flexibility *of* the vagina, and not for the vagina itself, its *existence,* flexible or otherwise; but this last is what the syntax actually implies. Thus substituting *because [of]* for *due to* will not fix the problem. One could, however, write something like the following:

> Aside from *the flexibility of the vagina* [noun phrase], which is *due to* the elasticity of the pelvic muscles, . . .

or

> Aside from the effect on the vagina, *which is/becomes flexible* [clause] *because of* [or, yes, *due to* or *owing to*] the elasticity of the pelvic muscles, . . .

Comment: +1 If I understand your point correctly, it is that this is not the sort of construction involving "due to" that purists object to. My impression has always been that any instance of "due to" that a reader can replace with "attributable to" without creating any problems with coherence is A-OK with the purist wing of Grammar, Incorporated.

Comment: @SvenYargs, I believe the purist wing would object to *due to* or *attributable to* in my second "[clause]" example above and to none of them in my first "[noun phrase]" example. It is my impression that they would nonetheless be OK with *owing to* in the second example, though why that should be more acceptable than *due to* (in predicating a cause of a clause) has never made any sense to me. I guess it is a "tribunal of use" thing, though once one accepts that jurisdiction the whole shibboleth shatters.